# Web API controller downloads csv but doesn't work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, csv, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple web api controller which I can navigate to through the url and it will download the .csv file. Now I am trying to write some jQuery where if you click the button it will download it but I am missing something.

```
public HttpStatusCode Get(string id)
{
    var reportString = AskWebBusiness.Reports.GenerationQuestionReport(id);
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "Questions Report.csv");
    response.Write(reportString);
    return HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

This code definitely works and I can go to the URL to prompt the download.

```
$('.js-btn-download-content').click(function (event) {
        var currentLanguage = getCulture();
        var url = baseUrl + 'report/get/' + currentLanguage;
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.loadingContent-download').fadeIn(200);
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 
                Accept : "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
                "Content-Type": "text/csv; charset=utf-8"
            },
            url: url,
            dataType: "text/csv",
            success: function (data) {
                $('.loadingContent-download').fadeOut(200);
                // Not sure about code below
                //var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
                //var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                //var $title = $xml.find("200");
                //if ($title) {
                    //$('.contentDownloaded-download p').html('Content donwloaded!');
                    //$('.contentDownloaded-download').show();
                //} else {
                    //$('.contentDownloaded-download p').html('Download failed! Please try again.');
                    //$('.contentDownloaded-download').show();
                //
            }
        });
        $('.js-btn-confirm').click(function () {
            $('.contentDownloaded-download').fadeOut(200);
        });
    });
```

As you can see, here is some javaScript that I've been using in the app to handle an OK being returned. However the browser won't download the file when this script fires. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your Get(string id) method, return the HttpResponseMessage instead of just the HttpStatusCode. Also, ASP.net Web API does not ensure the state of HttpContext.Current.Response (without some wizardry code). You can do something like, change the signature to Get(HttpRequestMessage request, string id) and then call request.CreateResponse(statusCode, data).